# Coldfusion SerializeJSON and deSerializeJSON is converting a string to number

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

ColdFusion is converting a string to number when passing to JS via a SerializeJSON and deSerializeJSON.

This is only happening when an 'E' is used between two set of numbers. like 3E6, 65E3, 56e45 etc. This is the code inside cfscript.

```
x = "2e9";
writedump(SerializeJSON(x));
writedump(deSerializeJSON(SerializeJSON(x)));

Output:
2.0E9 2000000000
```

Please suggest, if is there any other way for such issues.

Comment: Why are you serialising a variable that contains a string?  You only really need to serialise arrays or structures.

Comment: It's just a repro case, Simon: it will impact a similar string anywhere in a data structure being serialised.

Comment: It's weird, if i separate out the above code like this **<br>x = 2e9;<br>
       y = SerializeJSON(x); <br>
       z = deSerializeJSON(y);<br>
    writedump(z); **<br>, i get output 2000000000. Can anyone share some light on this?

Comment: @TusharBhaware: see my answer. 2e9 is scientific notation for 2000000000.

Comment: @AdamCameron, Thanks for answer. If you wouldn't have answered it, I would have been wondered about this a long time. I guess, it's time for me to check out the bugbase.

Answer (score 8):

It is this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3695627: "SerializeJSON turns strings that look like scientific notation into floats."

It's a known bug in CF9, and it's fixed in CF10.

In the meantime, you will just have to pad the string with something to force ColdFusion to not see it as a number in scientific notation.

Or upgrade to CF10 (CF9 is end of life next month, btw). Or to Railo.

Comment: Or try Ben's darn good serialization CFC. https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc

Comment: Yes Raymond, was just going through. Hope that will help... Thank you

Comment: Not fixed in ColdFusion 2016. SerializeJson converts 1519402896 to 1.519402896E9

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this using below solution

let's say ItemUnit = 12E45

```
stcReturn.firstname = "Yes";
stcReturn.lastname = "Man";
stcReturn.ItemUnit = "12E45"
```

error output after deSerializeJSON stcReturn.ItemUnit = 12e+46

```
<cfset stcReturn.ItemUnit  = ItemUnit />    
<cfset StructSetMetaData(stcReturn.ItemUnit, {ItemUnit : 
{"type":"string","name":"ItemUnit"}})/>

deSerializeJSON(stcReturn)
```

Correct Output:12E45