# Coldfusion 8 truncates number in JSON string but ColdFusion 10 does not

Tags: json, coldfusion, deserialization, coldfusion-8

This string:

`{"status":"ok","payload":{"total pages":1,"page":1,"total entities":1,"queryId":"1e93eb52-7421-4706-8eb9-f41f8ce7ff06","entities":[{"Entity ID":694000000269197}]}}`

when run through deserializeJson in CF10 produces what you would expect, but in CF8 the `entities[1]['Entity ID']` results in `6.94000000269E+014`.

What's going on and how can I get it to return the real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the CFLIB http://www.cflib.org/udf/jsondecode function instead of CF8s deserializeJSON function assuming it was just parsing the data wrong after reading this post: [Coldfusion SerializeJSON and deSerializeJSON is converting a string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015059/coldfusion-serializejson-and-deserializejson-is-converting-a-string-to-number)

Comment: That is a different issue. Your "Entity ID" is numeric, not a string. Looks like [the numeric value is the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586356/scientific-notation-with-precisionevaluate-in-coldfusion/18594912#18594912), only CF8 displays it with scientific notation and CF10.is not. If you dump out the class name of `entities[1]['Entity ID'].getClass().name`, what is the result?

Comment: I tried to use the result from the built in deserialization function but it had the notation in it, not the actual value. I have no idea how to get it to the real number. Using the CFLIB function worked for me. As to the WHY of all of this, I have no clue. I know CF8 is old, but I had to convert some stuff for a client so here I was.

Comment: Understood, but if you look at the link above, it explains why some numeric objects may be *displayed* with scientific notation. However, that does not mean the underlying number is different.  The link refers to BigDecimal values, but similar issues apply to other numeric types as well. I suspect that may explain the difference in your case.  BTW, nothing wrong with using the function. Just curious about the cause ..

Comment: It's not just displaying it though. I use that value and pass it back in another API call and I get an error that the id doesn't exist in the system. Makes no sense.

Comment: All depends on what is being passed an how it is interpreted. Hard to do more than guess without seeing the code. BTW,  I do not think you ever answered the earlier question.  What do you get when you dump out the class name on CF8 + 10:  `entities[1]['Entity ID'].getClass().name` ?